# Is the min-cut size of a directed graphs transpose the same as that of the original?

Tags: check-my-answer, minimum-cuts, directed-graphs

I was wondering whether the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose_graph) of graph maintains the same size of the minimal cut in a directed graph (digraph).

This may be trivial as I haven't been able to find anything here or on Google when searching for different variants of the query "directed graph transpose minimal cut preservation\conservation".

I decided to try to prove it and see where it gets me. My though process is as such, given a digraph with a set of vertices $A$ such that $|A| \leq |V|/2$ and it is known that $|C_G(A)|$ is the size of the min-cut in $G$  then all the edges from $A$ to $\bar{A} = V \setminus A$ in $G$ are now going from $\bar{A}$ to $A$ in $G^T$. Thus, the cut $C_{G^T}(\bar{A})$ is at least as big as $C_G(A)$.

Now, if we assume that $C_{G^T}(\bar{A}) > C_G(A)$ then that means there is some edge $(u,v) \in E^T$ such that $(v, u) \notin E$ in contradiction to the definition of $G^T$ as the transpose of $G$.

Therefore, $C_{G^T}(\bar{A})$ is a min-cut in $G^T$ of the same size as $C_G(A)$.

I haven't been able to think up a counterexample and would appreciate a verification of my proof or a counterexample.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Uri. The proof is correct. However, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I assumed since there is a "check-my-answer" tag that it is valid. Would it have been better if I posted this as a question with my own answer? I disagree that it has no value - if my proof would've been wrong there would have been great merit in an answer that both explains what's wrong with it and gives a correct proof (or a sketch of one). However, I have no way of knowing beforehand if I'm correct or not - that can only be determined in hindsight. Avoiding such questions just because there is a chance they won't have any insightful answers is counterproductive to the cause.

Comment: Hmmm. Somewhat agreed. :)